# Collect different info from different tables using Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5

I hope to get the solution of this problem. I have different tables, how can I make a custom collection to collect what I want from multiple tables(of course based on logical relationship) and make this collection to be returned as a json object using eloquent in laravel.

Comment: Please show these tables to make it easier to help.

Comment: Ok, just I want to know how can make a custom collection to be used to collect a data from table using eloquent of laravel and then convert this collection to a json object to be a response of http get verb.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax :

```
$myCollection = DB::table('Table1')->leftJoin('Table2','Table1.id','=','Table2.whatever'‌​‌​‌​‌​)->select('‌​Table1​.*','Table2.whatever')->orderBy('Table1.custom','DESC')->get‌​()‌​;
```

And if use just return the collection it's gonna be JSON by default 
or you can return like so

```
return response()->json(['Collection'=>$myCollection]);
```

Comment: @Nour Yasein it is good solution for QB schema, but what about eloquent structure, specially if we have many columns and need just few columns info to be returned.

Comment: If you want you can exclude them from your query you can achieve that easily as you can see from the code you can choose the whole table or specific columns as much as you wish just separate them with comma as for returning the final collection is an array of objects so call any member of the object or an index if results are many